# How come sometimes Django's development server hangs?

Tags: python, django

And just keeps "waiting for server..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's single-threaded, and you're making a second request to it from server code. Use a multithreaded or multiprocessed web server for testing instead.

**EDIT:**

This issue was [fixed](https://github.com/django/django/commit/ce165f7bbf0c481a20db6b4b9f764b8bb89348ba#diff-f6d1c75ec606389da5af6558bf57f171) about 5 months after this question was asked; this answer no longer applies to newer versions.

Comment: manage.py runserver is no longer single-threaded: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16099#comment:14

Comment: A downvote on a six-and-a-half-year-old answer. Awesome.

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to offend you, but that's just the world. An answer can become misleading over time, and that can result in confusion and wasted effort to "fix" a nonexisting problem. If you edit your answer to note that it's only relevant for old Django versions and is no longer applicable now, I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be a different reason, but at least in *my* case, it was due to Avast antivirus, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47362725/122441

As a precaution, turn off your antivirus temporarily, restart runserver and see if the problem persists. At least you've eliminated one potential issue.