# django manage.py runserver hangs after second request (intermittent)

Tags: python, django, web, antivirus

My Django 1.11 app (using runserver) hangs after several requests. It doesn't matter whether it's accessed by Chrome, Postman, or curl.

When it hangs, not even Ctrl+C can close it. The python.exe process must be killed.

I tried debugging it but when Django is stuck, Python cannot be paused to get the threads/stack.

Answer (score 2):

This actually happens to me due to Avast antivirus's Behavior Shield.

If you google it you find out that Avast has a long history of "hating" Python: https://www.google.co.id/search?q=avast+python

Solution: Avast > Settings > Components > Behavior Shield > Exclusions, then add your python.exe or your virtualenv's python.exe there:

[image: Avast]